# Google Links taking to wrong screen in asp.net, how to redirect to main page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Google search Links are taking to admin screen instead of the main screen for the public. How can I check in my code in ASP.Net Web forms to redirect from Admin login screen https://www.xxxxx.com/Admin/login to main site https://www.xxxxx.com? Admin Login screen is for only admins. Whoever searches are being taken to Admin site which is misleading. I use ASP.NET Webforms with C#. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a meta tag in your admin login page's head

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

This will tell google not to index your admin login page and ultimately removing this page from search result. (might take couple days to take effect depending on the crawling cycle)

Comment: Thank you for a quick solution, I will try it.